# Что лучше, SplFileObject или fopen и т.д.?

Tags: php

Что лучше использовать при работе с файлами, Что лучше, SplFileObject или fopen и т.д. ? И в чем основное отличие ?

Comment: Дайте определение понятию "лучше".

Comment: не ясно что обсуждать, если первое это обертка над вторым. Какие у вас еще есть "и т.д." варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Дело не в "лучшести" или "хужести". 
Из документации

> Класс [SplFileObject](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.splfileobject.php) предоставляет объектно-ориентированный интерфейс
>   для файла.

Сие означает лишь то, что вы будете работать с файлом в ООП стиле. По сути это облегчит вам работу, несомненно ибо вам не нужно думать о том, как это работает уровнем ниже.